# Can workflows run with an expired SSL on the SharePoint server 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager, ssl

Can workflows run with an expired SSL on the SharePoint server 2013? what will be the impact?

Answer (score 1):

When the certificate expires, the Workflow Manager service will not start.

This might affect the state of your workflows.

A better way would be to update the certificate before it expires:

1. [How to update OutboundCertificate in Workflow Manager (and SharePoint)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/feseca/2014/09/23/how-to-update-outboundcertificate-in-workflow-manager-and-sharepoint/).
2. [Workflow Manager Farms for SharePoint 2013 Part Three: Switching an existing farm to use Domain CA issued certificates](http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm3.aspx).

Comment: 2nd link isnt working

Comment: I have replaced it with another great article where you should get everything documented